# On button click previously pressed button's value is set to blank

Tags: javascript, html

I've created multiple buttons in HTML, and have a onclick function specified. When I click a button, the correct actions happen (the value changes, etc.) However when I click another button, the previously clicked button has its value set to nothing.

HTML Button Creation: (I'm using flask, so things in {{}} get replaced)

```
<button type="button" id="{{ button.name }}" onclick="buttonClicked(this.id)">{{ button.name }}</button>
```

Javascript `buttonClicked` function:

```
function buttonClicked(buttonID){
     console.log("button clicked (running from render.js)")
     Http.open("GET", "http://localhost:5000/buttonClicked/buttonClicked");
     Http.send();
     Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
          console.log(Http.responseText)
          //buttonID.innerHTML = Http.responseText;
          el = document.getElementById(buttonID);
          el.innerHTML = String(Http.responseText);
     }
};
```

I've also tried using `<input>` like so:

```
<input id="{{ button.name }}" type="button" onclick="buttonClicked(this.id)" value="RegA" />
```

Edit: example of what happens when the button is clicked
First button clicked:

```
<button type="button" id="button1" onclick="buttonClicked(this.id)"></button>
```

Second button clicked:

```
<button type="button" id="button2" onclick="buttonClicked(this.id)">buttonClicked returned from python</button>
```

Comment: why not storing  the clicked button in javascript variable?

Comment: The buttons are created from a dictionary in Python, so that's why I don't define them as a variable in javascript. If you look at the buttonClicked function, I do store the button temporarily to a variable so I can set its innerHTML

Comment: Can you try to add a ```let ``` before ```el = document.getElementById(buttonID);``` ? Not sure if this fixes the issue

Comment: Sure. 
But it looks like it has the same issue.

Comment: I've also tried using `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`. Is that the more proper way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a separate XMLHttpRequest object for each click event inside the `buttonClicked` function.

```
function buttonClicked(buttonID) {
    let Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log("button clicked (running from render.js)")
    Http.open("GET", "http://localhost:5000/buttonClicked/buttonClicked");
    Http.send();
    // ....
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gh68qrtx/

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks so much for your help!